# Timezone calculation

Tags: iphone, xcode, timezone

How to find out the current time in different timezone in xcode for an iphone application?
Suppose i'm in India and i want to know the current time in USA how do i get the time then.

Thanks in advance
Joy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Introduction to Date and Time Programming Guide for Cocoa.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html)

There are built-in methods for handling timezones.