# How to obtain current timezone in objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to get time zone for the current location such as -5 or +3 and so on. I am unable to do so. I am using datecomponents:

```
// Turn the date into Integers
NSInteger year = [dateComponents year];
NSInteger month = [dateComponents month];
NSInteger day = [dateComponents day];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Timezone calculation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552134/timezone-calculation)

Answer (score 6):

```
NSDateFormatter *date_formater=[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[date_formater setDateFormat:@"Z"];
NSString * tz=[date_formater stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

Comment: Thanks Aaron! I also found  tzsecs = ([[NSTimeZone localTimeZone] secondsFromGMT])/3600;